# Google charts api - joining 3 json strings using google.visualization.data.join

Tags: json, google-visualization

I want to parse 3 separate data sets to my chart.draw() function. I've read that this is not possible so I must use the google.visualization.data.join() function to join them together. How ever I seem to be having trouble joining 3 json strings.I've tried this (as the function only takes two variables):

```
var joinedData1 = google.visualization.data.join(json1, json2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]); 
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData1, json3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

But when I draw the chart it seems to only draw the lines of "json1" and "json3".

How can I draw the 3 lines from separate datasets?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue but i'm not using JSON strings. The problem here is

```
google.visualization.data.join(dt1, dt2, joinMethod,                                keys, dt1Columns, dt2Columns);
```

You have mentioned only one column of dt1(joinedData1) so only the first column of the joinedData1 is joined with json3

Current:-

```
var joinedData1 = google.visualization.data.join(json1, json2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]); 
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData1, json3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

To be changed :-

```
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData1, json3, 'full', [[0, 0]], **[1,2]**, [1]);
```